# Set bean property from JSF page

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I need to do very simple thing - pass current URL from JSF (2.0) page to the managed bean. This is needed to get URL of the login form which will redirect user back to the current page after login. (I use GAE and the bean is the wrapping around its user service, if it does matter). Any obvious way I tried doesn't work
`<c:set />` - doesn't work (w/o any error or warning message)
getter which takes current URL as a parameter - doesn't work.
So many questions and many recipes, but all are complex and not elegant. Why? May be I (as other who asking) missed a key design principle? I'll appreciate any answer - simple and straightforward recipe or explanation why not to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available by [`#{request.requestURL}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) (or if you only want the domain-relative path, use [`#{request.requestURI}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29)). Use [`f:param`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/param.html) to pass it and [`@ManagedProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) to handle it.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.submit}" value="submit">
    <f:param name="url" value="#{request.requestURL}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

with

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.url}")
private String url;
```

Noted should be that `f:param` inside a [`h:commandButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html) doesn't work in JSF 1.x. You'd like to use [`h:commandLink`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandLink.html) instead.

---

**Update** as per the comments: I understood that you wanted to "pass current URL to the managed bean". But you actually want to "access current URL in managed bean".

In that case, *either* replace `#{param.url}` by `#{request.requestURL}`:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{request.requestURL}")
private String url;
```

*Or* obtain the raw [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) instance from under the JSF hoods by [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest%28%29):

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
String requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that it will work, when user press submit button. But can I set some bean property without any interaction with user? I need to initialize a bean property with the specific requestURI just after HTTP GET request is received and be able to get other property which depends on the requestURI below on the page. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it was my fault, I'm sorry for ambiguous question. Now both options work do exactly what I need! Thank you BalusC!

Comment: @Odelya: Only when the scope of the property is shorter than the bean's scope. In this particular example the property is request scoped, then the bean must be request scoped, it can't have a broader scope than that.